# AngularJS Numbers and Return

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

is there a way to use AngularJS to only accept Numbers and Return (/n/r) in a textarea?
similarly like this:

```
<textarea>
2344
5335
55555
2222
234
</textarea>
```

Above is just an example of what I am trying to restrict the text area to. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/textarea

Theoretically you can use ngPattern like this:

```
ngPattern="/[0-9\r\n]*/"
```

With this setting the textarea will enable anything to type, but treats only numbers and returns as valid.

Probably you can use for example ngChange, to filter out anything non-valid.

Comment: angularJS does not add a class to the textarea when the pattern is invalid.